# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when access != nil static var

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift5

Context: The app needs to be connected to a bluetooth device 100% of the time. While using the app, the CBPeripheral object is stored in a static variable for use throughout the user's session in app.

```
//This is in AppDelegate class.
static var connectedDevice: CBPeripheral? = nil
```

.........

```
class BluetoothScanner : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {


//(...)

func connectToDevice(peripheral: CBPeripheral)
 {
    AppDelegate.connectedDevice = peripheral
    
    //(...)
    
 }
```

}

At the start of the app, access operations to that variable occur in a loop. The first accesses to the variable are correct. But always, before ending the loop (at about 40 access to var), it happens EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
        if(AppDelegate.connectedDevice != nil)
        {
          //Thread 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16ec8ff28)  
          print("Device debug: " +  AppDelegate.connectedDevice!.debugDescription)
          
        }
```

The problem occurs when calling 'debugDescription' but the same problem occurs when calling any other function of 'connectedDevice'

AppDelegate.connectedDevice is only accessed (in that period) it is never modified, nor released.

I have tested the app for two weeks very thoroughly and without problems. But when uploading it to the AppStore it indicated that I needed to update the XCode to the latest version in order to upload compilation to the AppStore. This problem has appeared without touching the code, only updating the XCode. I have even tested (before updating XCode) that this object is not released during hours of use of the app.

Comment: Don't test for `!= nil` and then force unwrap. Use `if let..` to conditionally unwrap.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the tip, but that's not the problem, the same thing happens.

Comment: this is because you are trying to access `AppDelegate` not on main thread. You should either always access that variable on main thread, or (better option) move it out of AppDelegate.

Comment: @ Kiril S. This is not the problem. I try to store static var in different classes. I have even forced that variable is always accessed from the interface thread (only for test).